# How to find out which included files are not part of current VC++ solution

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Among other things, I would imagine a Visual C++ solution is meant to encompass all source code files for a given product. However, thanks to the "Additional Include Directories" and the built-in C++ ability to include absolute and relative paths -- it is possible to include files that are not part of the solution (starting w/ the standard C++ headers).

This can happen both by mistake and on purpose. However, in order to keep dependencies under control and a good overview of which files are the product's source code and which files are built-in Visual Studio files, it would be great if there were a way to tell which includes are not part of the current solution.

See this example:

1. C:/Dev/Projects/Project-A/Project-A.vcproj
2. C:/Dev/Projects/Project-A/Project-B.vcproj
3. C:/Dev/Projects/Project-A/Project-C.vcproj
4. C:/Dev/Projects/Project-A/Project-D.vcproj

If I create a solution, which only contains **Project-A**, and **Project-B**, there is nothing preventing **Project-A** to include files from under **Project-C** and **Project-D**. This means that if for example I wish to distribute this solution, I might overlook Project-C and Project-D.

Can we get VC++ to give a warning about source code files that are not explicitly part of the solution -- outside of course, the standard C++ headers? Or at least provide a full list of files that are eventually included in the final library/executable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include files that are not a part of the project usually automatically placed in the "External Dependencies" folder of the project in Solution Explorer.

Comment: This is very good to know, thanks. Just learned, that in VS 2005 (which I use), this feature does not work, accordingly to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820990

Comment: Just checked w/ VS 2010 and the External Dependencies folder seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can show all included files with the [`/showIncludes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)-switch.

Other than that, I don't think there is an automatic way to prevent inclusion of certain files. You simply have to watch out for it.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! The /showIncludes switch seems to only output the expanded #include "...." path, which is relative most of the times, relative to the referencing file. Is there a way to expand it to absolute paths?